# HW rendering to Android Surface using OpenMAX IL

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-library, openmax

I would like to utilize OMX HW renderer as described here: 
http://www.slideshare.net/RaghavanVenkateswaran/iomx-in-android

**OS:** Android 2.3.4

**System libaries used:** libmedia, libbinder, libstagefright, libutils

**OMX components on my device:**

componentName: OMX.ITTIAM.AAC.decode, componentRole: audio_decoder.aac

componentName: OMX.ITTIAM.AAC.encode, componentRole: audio_encoder.aac

componentName: OMX.TI.720P.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.mpeg4

componentName: OMX.TI.720P.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.avc

componentName: OMX.TI.720P.Encoder, componentRole: video_encoder.mpeg4

componentName: OMX.TI.720P.Encoder, componentRole: video_encoder.avc

componentName: OMX.TI.AAC.decode, componentRole: audio_decoder.aac

componentName: OMX.TI.AAC.encode, componentRole: audio_encoder.aac

componentName: OMX.TI.AMR.decode, componentRole: audio_decoder.amrnb

componentName: OMX.TI.AMR.encode, componentRole: audio_encoder.amrnb

componentName: OMX.TI.Camera, componentRole: camera.yuv

componentName: OMX.TI.JPEG.decoder, componentRole: image_decoder.jpeg

componentName: OMX.TI.JPEG.encoder, componentRole: image_encoder.jpeg

componentName: OMX.TI.MP3.decode, componentRole: audio_decoder.mp3

componentName: OMX.TI.VPP, componentRole: iv_renderer.yuv.overlay

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.h263

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.avc

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.mpeg2

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.mpeg4

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.Decoder, componentRole: video_decoder.wmv

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.encoder, componentRole: video_encoder.mpeg4

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.encoder, componentRole: video_encoder.h263

componentName: OMX.TI.Video.encoder, componentRole: video_encoder.avc

componentName: OMX.TI.WBAMR.decode, componentRole: audio_decoder.amrwb

componentName: OMX.TI.WBAMR.encode, componentRole: audio_encoder.amrwb

componentName: OMX.TI.WMA.decode, componentRole: audio_decoder.wma

**I have done these steps:**

1, Passed the Android Surface object through the JNI that way (exactly as in the native MediaPlayer):

**JNI (C++):**

```
static void com_mautilus_media_MMediaPlayer_setVideoSurface(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "setVideoSurface");

    MMediaPlayer *mp = getMediaPlayer(env, thiz);

    if (mp == NULL )
    {
        jniThrowException(env, "java/lang/IllegalStateException", NULL);
        return;
    }

    setVideoSurface(mp, env, thiz);

}
static void setVideoSurface(MMediaPlayer *mp, JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "setVideoSurface");

    jobject surface = env->GetObjectField(thiz, fields.surface);

    if (surface != NULL && mp != NULL)
    {
        const android::sp<android::Surface> native_surface = get_surface(env, surface);
        mp->setVideoSurface(native_surface);

    }
}
```

Surface variable in MMediaPlayer is declared as:

```
android::sp<android::Surface> surface;
```

**Java:**

```
private Surface mSurface; // accessed by native methods
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;

public void setDisplay(SurfaceHolder sh)
{
    mSurfaceHolder = sh;

    if (sh != null)
    {
        mSurface = sh.getSurface();
    }
    else
    {
        mSurface = null;
    }

    setVideoSurface(); // Native function call
}
```

**2, Initialized the IOMX node:**

Note: hardcoded values are there only for simplicity and testing purposes

```
android::sp<android::IServiceManager> serviceManager = android::defaultServiceManager();
android::sp<android::IBinder> binder = serviceManager>getService(android::String16("media.player"));
android::sp<android::IMediaPlayerService> mediaPlayerService = android::interface_cast<android::IMediaPlayerService>(binder);
android::sp<android::IOMX> iomx = mediaPlayerService->getOMX();


android::IOMX::node_id node;

// observer is instance of class derived from android::BnOMXObserver class
iomx->allocateNode("OMX.TI.VPP", observer, &mRendererNode->node);

OMX_PARAM_PORTDEFINITIONTYPE portDefn;
portDefn.nPortIndex = 1;

iomx->getParameter(node, OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition, &portDefn, sizeof(portDefn));

//portDefn.nBufferCountActual = mInBufCnt; // set some suitable value here or don’t update to
//use default value

portDefn.format.video.nFrameWidth = 256; // width of the video to be played
portDefn.format.video.nFrameHeight = 144; // height of video to be played
portDefn.format.video.nStride = 256;
portDefn.format.video.nSliceHeight = 144;
iomx->setParameter(node, OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition, &portDefn, sizeof(portDefn));


portDefn.nPortIndex = 2;
iomx->getParameter(node, OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition, &portDefn, sizeof(portDefn));
//portDefn.nBufferCountActual = iOutBufCnt; // set suitable value or leave to default.
portDefn.nBufferSize = (256 * 144 * 3) / 2;
portDefn.format.video.nFrameWidth = 256;
portDefn.format.video.nFrameHeight = 144;
portDefn.format.video.nStride = 256;
portDefn.format.video.nSliceHeight = 144;
iomx->setParameter(node, OMX_IndexParamPortDefinition, &portDefn, sizeof(portDefn));
```

**3, Tried to create the OMX Renderer:**

```
android::sp<android::IOMXRenderer> mOMXRenderer;

mOMXRenderer = omxContext->iomx->createRenderer(surface, "OMX.TI.VPP", OMX_COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar, 256, 144, displayWidth, displayHeight, 0);
```

which always returns NULL.

Has anybody an idea what’s wrong with that? Am I initializing wrong component? Or there must be followed some special calling sequence? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Use createRendererFromJavaSurface defined in IOMX.h